# importing training data to CloudML with images that do not have a file-extension

Tags: google-vision, automl

i created some training data and put the CSV in the google-storage, but it looks like the import won't work when the files do not have a proper .jpg extension:

> Error: INVALID_ROW: Invalid input found at row 1 of gs://weg-li-production/training/test.csv: "Unsupported file extension."

values look like this:

> TRAIN,gs://weg-li-production/d7nwcheo8774rvbcgj4lyta3athj,Opel

is there a way to work around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you put the whole "TRAIN,gs://weg-li-production/d7nwcheo8774rvbcgj4lyta3athj,Opel" into a single unit in your csv file. The comma should represent another unit in the csv file. You can open it in Excel to check your csv file, and the correct format should include three columns in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `gs://weg-li-production/d7nwcheo8774rvbcgj4lyta3athj` is the image file & `Opel` is the label. It all looks fine, just that the image file name does not have a valid extension.

Check https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/prepare for valid file types (extension), during training & predictions

Comment: well yes, that's exactly the problem i am describing. the files are stored like this through a library and i would like to use it that way without having to copy any of the files around or renaming them, because i'd have to rename them in the database as well